# Authentication with Kerberos not working

Tags: active-directory, iis-7.5, kerberos

I have big problem.
I already search over the internet and no result

I am trying to use Kerberos between 3 OS of `Windows server 2008 R2`

> 1. Is the DC, the KDC and all the AD DS
> 2. The IIS server that run the website With negotiate
> 3. PC normally that react as Client/user of the domain

The problem is that all as I did from like 28 different websites that explain how to use kerberos with IIS and no result

The Result right now is the IIS webserver work on Negotiate option
and when I enter with the client it does `NTLM` and `No Kerberos`
and I have checked everything

```
 SPN/Authentication/DNS/AD SPN delegation(kerberos only)
```

What did I miss?